# Customized border-bottom for links is also shown on images and navigation

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm currently setting up a wordpress website and would like to customize the design of links. I made use of the following code:

```
a:link {
    color: inherit;
    transition: color 0.1s ease-in 0s, background-color 0.1s ease-in 0s, border-bottom-color 0.1s ease-in 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(238, 0, 0);
}

a:hover {
    color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 0, 0);
}
```

But after using this code basically everything got the border-bottom design. Menulinks, the logo, images with links etc. are shown with border-bottom after adding this code. But I would like to have this design applied only to external links and internal links within content. How to distinguish here, does anybody have an idea?

With a plugin I was able to add classes to at least the external links, but I don't have a clue how to also apply this to the internal links which are within content and not in the menu, logo, images etc.

Many thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want is to add your new styles only to links *inside body text*:

with the CSS you have right now, everything that is wrapped in an `<a>` tag is going to have these styles applied. What you want to do is specify your CSS selectors more. Try and right click -> inspect a link you want those styles to be applied to, and figure out if the inline links have any kind of unique class applied to them (i.e "link_inline"), then you would for example do `a.link_inline {/* your CSS */}`.

Another method would be to find a unique class of any parent element of all text on the page (i.e "content_wrapper"). Then you would do `.content_wrapper a {/*your CSS */}`